# Jenkins does not pick /usr/local/bin for executing job in Mac

Tags: macos, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently working on a jenkins build from a mac slave where I see the jenkins job gets terminated throwing

```
   mac $ /usr/bin/bash -xe /var/folders/zr/yj9xh_nd1950kz3shxqn587w0000gn/T/jenkins8432234567630369833.sh
    FATAL: command execution failed
    java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tried exporting the path in bash_profile too using `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` still it does not help .what I am doing wrong here

Comment: In Mac OS, it is /bin/bash. You can check that by running "which bash". For you second point, if your Mac is connected as a Jenkins slave via ssh than it leverages the bashrc file rather bash_profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I solved it using pre build steps